# Enlarge text key binding Firefox 9

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Lately (since Firefox 8 and 9) I have noticed that while I tab the left Ctrl button it will enlarge the text the way Ctrl++ would. It is incredibly annoying and I have to compensate with Ctrl+0.

Now it doesn't happen everytime I hit Ctrl. I can't predict it.

I've looked in about:config to see if I can see anything that stuck out. I didn't.

Any ideas where I could disable the ability to enlarge text or why this is happening?

Ubuntu 11.10 64bit 
EDIT: Also on a Ubuntu 10.04 32bit VM

Comment: Does this happen when you press **CTRL** and **middle click** (e.g. to open a link in a new tab)? You could be scrolling with the middle button. **CTRL+Scroll** changes the zoom.

Comment: I read your comment a couple days ago and wanted to give a few days to respond after I noticed if I'd left my fingers on the mousepad. No, in fact, I noticed it happens when I hold the left Ctrl key down for a second before tapping the tab key to cycle through tabs. So, just the Ctrl key is pressed and the page enlarges.

Comment: Still happening in FF 10 btw. Simply holding the left ctrl key for a split second enlarges the page.